# Unable to print multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, json

My requirement is to access json response, store it in php variable so that i will insert those variables into database.  Here's my code

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('dealdetails.json');
$array = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$arrlength = count($array);
echo $arrlength;

for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) 
{
    //echo $x;
    $PromoID = $array[$x]['PromoID'];
    $OfferID = $array[$x]['OfferID'];
    $OfferName = $array[$x]['OfferName'];
    $Type = $array[$x]['Type'];
    $Code = $array[$x]['Code'];
    $Title = $array[$x]['Title'];
    $Description = $array[$x]['Description'];
    $Category = $array[$x]['Category'];
    $OfferPage = $array[$x]['OfferPage'];
    $DateAdded = $array[$x]['DateAdded'];
    $Expiry = $array[$x]['Expiry'];

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Unable to get the values assigned during iteration

Example : 
$array[0]['promoId'] is working
Where as $array[$x]['promoId'] is not working.

Json sample request :

```
[{"featured":"0","exclusive":"1","promo_id":"xxx","offer_id":"x","offer_name":"xxx","coupon_title":"xx","category":"","coupon_description":"","coupon_type":"Coupon","coupon_code":"xxx","ref_id":"xxx","link":"xxx","coupon_expiry":"2017-03-31","added":"2016-01-05","preview_url":"http:\/\/www.stalkbuylove.com\/","store_link":"http:\/\/tracking.vcommission.com\/aff_c?offer_id=230&aff_id=43367"},
[{"featured":"0","exclusive":"1","promo_id":"xxx","offer_id":"x","offer_name":"xxx","coupon_title":"xx","category":"","coupon_description":"","coupon_type":"Coupon","coupon_code":"xxx","ref_id":"xxx","link":"xxx","coupon_expiry":"2017-03-31","added":"2016-01-05","preview_url":"http:\/\/www.stalkbuylove.com\/","store_link":"http:\/\/tracking.vcommission.com\/aff_c?offer_id=230&aff_id=43367"},
```

Please suggest.

Comment: it's really hard to understand your question, please rephrase it.

Comment: @OfirBaruch : Sorry for the inconvenience caused . Rephrased the question Please suggest

Comment: $array[x] would be $array[$x],  $x for value even not '$x'

Comment: @developerCK : it is $PromoID= $array[$x]['PromoID']; only; typo error.  thanks

Comment: it would be better if you gives what `$jsondata` hold.
also
`echo $array['$x']['PromoID'];`
should be
`echo $array[$x]['PromoID'];`

Comment: echo $array['$x']['PromoID'];, i am talking about this, in your code after for loop. ['$x'] ?

Comment: Show `print_r($array);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('dealdetails.json');
$array = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    //print_r($value);

    echo $value['PromoID'];
    $PromoID = $value['PromoID'];
    $OfferID = $value['OfferID'];
    $OfferName = $value['OfferName'];
    $Type = $value['Type'];
    $Code = $value['Code'];
    $Title = $value['Title'];
    $Description = $value['Description'];
    $Category = $value['Category'];
    $OfferPage = $value['OfferPage'];
    $DateAdded = $value['DateAdded'];
    $Expiry = $value['Expiry'];

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Using [`foreach()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is the proper way to iterate through an array.

Also note that the sample JSON you provided uses `promo_id` instead of `PromoID`, so you'd want `$value['promo_id']`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Comment: Will some small help.  Actually the json file which i am using now is actually the output of web service call.  Can i directly use that web service response instead of copying into file and then use it?

Comment: If you get JSON as a string, you can just pass that string to `json_decode()` without the file.

Comment: Thanks Will.  I will do some r&d to get knowledge on this.